# How to pass user defined key in aes_encrypt?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, encryption

I have an entity file. I have used @ColumnTransformer to encrypt the data in fields and passed aes_encrypt and aes_decrypt in write and read attribute. 
However my concern is that since my key is in a Java file, the class file can be decompiled and key can be exposed.
Is there a way that I can store the key in some other file and use that variable for specifying key?

@ColumnTransformer(write="aes_encrypt(column name, **key**)

I am using spring boot , jpa, MySQL,and hibernate.

Comment: Have you considered using obfuscation tools such as ProGuard https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard?

Comment: I not really interested in using some external tool as it makes my application dependent on third party tools...

Comment: Did you get a work around for this ? I also have similar requirement

Comment: no i didnt get any work around for it. We removed the use of column transformer and went on create hbm fies.